# Monitor print requests and add a header

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm wanting to write a program in vb .net that could monitor outgoing print requests from any program on the PC, prompt the user if they would like to add a header to the document, and if they say yes, then tack it on (if the user has printed something in the space where the header will go, just print on top of it).

Is this possible?  I've looked around for ideas on how to do this, but I can't seem to find anything.  Any good ideas or resources out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like you'd want to create a virtual printer that passed jobs on to an actual printer.  The user would print to your virtual printer.  I have NO experience with this, but here are some links to content that may assist.

http://www.pdfpilot.com/virtual-printer-howto-vb-net.html

[Writing a Virtual Printer in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257768/writing-a-virtual-printer-in-net)

http://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinterpilot.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I believe that is exactly what I need.