# help for a new person looking to code vb

Tags: c++, vb.net, printing, printers

i am looking to use vb for my final year university project.

what i want to do is after a user presses print from word for example, an vb application to appear asking the user if they want to send the print job and then sends it, the aim of this application will be eventually be able to send print jobs from home to another destination, would v.b. work for this idea, or is another language better and where do i start ?

Thanks !

Comment: Am i correct in understanding the reason this is tagged with [c++] is because its the language you *do* know and ware just wondering if VB.Net can do what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, yes i do know c++, java, haskell, python, 

new to visual basic and i have thought about other languages but i really don't know which is most suitable for this idea, a few of my mates have recommend v.b. to me

Comment: Ah, ok. that makes a lot more sense. As much as it pains me to say it, VB has come a LONG way since the day (3.0 was my first exposure) and now that it is second only to C# for CLI languages, there is very little you can't do with it. (running native on my Ubuntu box not-withstanding). So yeah, I see no reason you couldn't do this. Se e @Jay s answer for a v-printer sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer [Writing a Virtual Printer in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257768/writing-a-virtual-printer-in-net) has some good info, specifically the posts about the windows driver development kit.