# How do I add features to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Let's say that when I installed Visual Studio 2017 I decided to use the "Windows Universal Platform" packages.  Later, I realize that I'd like to install the ".Net Desktop packages" (either instead, or in addition).

How can I go back and add those features to Visual Studio 2017?  Is there a way to do this within Visual Studio?  Do I have to re-run the installer?

Comment: Just re-run the installer and add the extra workloads.

Comment: There's a reason the installer is a start menu item in its own right rather than only being accessible through the Programs control panel.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can go to tools from menu bar and then select "Get tools and features" and then you can add or modify your features.

[image]

Comment: Any idea why "Get tools and features" option would be missing from the Tools menu? I have 2 machines running VS 2017 Enterprise and only see the option on one of the computers.

Answer (score 21):

Re-run the visual studio launcher and click on modify. Make your edits and the launcher install the missing components.

Comment: It's worth adding (from the comment on the question by Damien_The_Unbeliever) that the Visual Studio Installer is actually added to the Start Menu, and is capable of updating itself as well as VS.

Comment: In my Start menu is only the VS17 installer, with admin rights to install updates direct.

Comment: Is there a way to launch it directly from visual studio? 

A little context: when there's suggested updates you can launch the installer right from VS.

Comment: I know no way to launch the Installer from VS. It's not possible because if you modify your installation you need to close VS for the installation. But for Updates you could use Tools->Extensions/Updates->Updates

Answer (score 13):

After you have installed Visual Studio 2017 you will have a program called `Visual Studio Installer`. Launch this application.

[image]

From here you can select modify and then add the components that you need.

[image]